# ProxyPass, ServletContext name with resource links not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, proxypass

Okay I have a spring MVC web app packaged as www-coolapp.war and deployed to a tomcat server. I have a domain name www.coolap.com and I would like to map all requests from localhost:8080/www-coolapp to www.coolap.com. In my apache configuration I am using the following in a virtual host

```
ProxyRequests                   off
ProxyPreserveHost               on
ProxyPass                       / http://localhost:8080/www-coolapp/
ProxyPassReverse                / http://localhost:8080/www-coolapp/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath      /www-coolapp /
```

This basically works except for files in the resources directory. In my spring context I have resources configured as

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

in my JSP files I declare the links using `<c:url>` which prepends the servlet context name to the beginning of the URLs.

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Deployed to the server these translate to

```
<link href="/www-coolapp/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/www-coolapp/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Which does not render correctly i.e. links to files in resources (css, images, javascript, etc.) are broken links based on the servlet context name being prepended to the path.

Is there a way to modify the proxy settings or rewrite the urls to make this work without changing all the links in the webapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - per the jstl doc adding a `context` attribute overwrites the servlet context name and now the links resolve correctly with the ProxyPass config.

```
<a href="<c:url context="/" value="..."/>">Lint Text</a>
```

Probably should have slept on this one before posting...